# NullPointer in getGraphics() in JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel

Hey I get a NullPointerException when trying to use a Graphics object inside paintComponent and I cannot figure out why. It still draws what I want once, but after that, it throws the exception. Heres the code

```
public class RacePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, ActionListener
{

private static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 400;
private Timer time;
boolean firstTime;
private Rabbit hare;

public RacePanel()
{
    setSize(PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    firstTime = true;
    addKeyListener(new Key());
    addMouseListener(this);
    hare = new Rabbit();
    time = new Timer(40, this);
    time.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawLine(0, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight()/2);
    g.drawLine(this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight()/2, 2*this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight());
    g.drawLine(2*this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight(), 3*this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight()/2);
    g.drawLine(3*this.getWidth()/4, this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    g.fillOval(hare.getPosition(), this.getHeight()-10, 10, 10);


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    paintComponent(g);
    hare.move();

}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    RacePanel panel = new RacePanel();
    panel.setVisible(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setMinimumSize(panel.getSize());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addKeyListener(panel.new Key());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Once it hits the g=getGraphics() g is null and the call for super.paintComponent(g) throws the exception. I copied a lot of the animation code from one of my previous projects and everything works fine on there so I am pretty confused why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    paintComponent(g);
    hare.move();

}
```

is NOT how custom painting in Swing works.  There is NEVER any reason why you should be calling `paintComponent` (or even `paint`) directly, they are called by the painting sub system.

Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how the painting system works

If you want the UI to be updated, you should be calling `repaint`, which will schedule a paint pass for some time in the future

You may also want to have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which will help solve the reliability issues related to `KeyListener`

If you'd prefer "complete" control over the painting process, you might consider having a look at [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html), although, this is a complete shift in thinking